# Download Access Denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, appx

## Introduction

Hi! Im trying to download application content-types from Microsoft TLU Delivery. Upon downloading, its always resulted with corrupted files. The downloaded files just have 1kb size, meanwhile the original ones have 200kb+. I already trying to use custom headers and cookies on the Download Module but its still the same. Here's my network connection that i get from chrome console :

```
Request URL: http://tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/f7ded4c4-f468-4bdc-96f0-03fd60c5ae81?p1=1604760658&p2=402&p3=2&p4=hcdsxul%2f8qkk8gjjjyomq0ki%2bxwjxulxxeninyf1jqrp3%2bsnzk%2fpwk4dgsnbkfzkzoor4%2bvaixilmxk6r%2bz6%2ba%3d%3d
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 8.241.131.254:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
#Response Header
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 240667
Cache-Control: public, max-age=17280000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement_10.0.19011.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Appx
Content-Length: 281728
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Sat, 21 Nov 2020 22:49:40 GMT
ETag: "cP6LQFFTB9bLaXCyN/YHr8kWbqM="
Expires: Wed, 09 Jun 2021 22:49:58 GMT
g: g
Last-Modified: Wed, 30 Jan 2019 14:28:15 GMT
MS-CorrelationId: c93312f7-dc52-41ef-b2d2-9294c1deda19
MS-CV: /24yhmSg0EivGZOl.0.3.8.2.1.0.0.22.2.6.2.1.1.0
MS-RequestId: 9378576c-a791-4636-93bf-7b8ef57c85a3
MSRegion: APAC
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
x-ccc: SG
x-cid: 3
X-MS-Ref-OriginShield: Ref A: 4127806A5D794419ACF51D29DD883F50 Ref B: BAYEDGE0319 Ref C: 2019-01-30T14:32:41Z
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 6F76857D59174A4BA37F3076DE6671DC Ref B: SJCEDGE0406 Ref C: 2019-01-30T14:32:41Z
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
#Request header
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.282065737.1604285823; MUID=07B92E6562A266AE0A83211366A260EF; AAMC_mscom_0=REGION%7C3; aam_uuid=33272659623977483402062764826775668547; mbox=PC#f8f94dce007c4a3c88788082771689c3.38_0#1668947906|session#af45a09527ce4486be93aff7c2a9adf1#1605704965; _cs_c=0; _cs_id=cd07a4b3-19b2-a8c7-95e4-7b8fd7c286f9.1605703107.1.1605703107.1605703107.1594299326.1639867107380.Lax.0; _uetvid=c457b5101e8a11eb956e2f93309fcf0c; IR_PI=f62c6991-299a-11eb-980c-0abbe301118c%7C1605789507507
DNT: 1
Host: tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36
#Query String
p1: 1604760658
p2: 402
p3: 2
p4: hcdsxul/8qkk8gjjjyomq0ki+xwjxulxxeninyf1jqrp3+snzk/pwk4dgsnbkfzkzoor4+vaixilmxk6r+z6+a==
```

## Problematic

Here's several download module that i've try:

```
from clint import textui
from clint.textui import progress
import urllib.request
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener
from tqdm import tqdm
class DownloadProgressBar(tqdm):
    def update_to(self, b=1, bsize=1, tsize=None):
        if tsize is not None:
            self.total = tsize
        self.update(b * bsize - self.n)
def CookDown(url, filename):
    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'}
    cookies = {'_ga': 'GA1.2.282065737.1604285823', 'MUID': '07B92E6562A266AE0A83211366A260EF','aam_uuid': '33272659623977483402062764826775668547','AAMC_mscom_0': 'REGION%7C3','_cs_c': '0','_cs_id': 'cd07a4b3-19b2-a8c7-95e4-7b8fd7c286f9.1605703107.1.1605703107.1605703107.1594299326.1639867107380.Lax.0','_uetvid': 'c457b5101e8a11eb956e2f93309fcf0c','IR_PI': 'f62c6991-299a-11eb-980c-0abbe301118c%7C1605789507507','mbox': 'PC#f8f94dce007c4a3c88788082771689c3.38_0#1668947906|session#af45a09527ce4486be93aff7c2a9adf1#1605704965'}
    try:
        read = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as w:
            for chunk in read.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
                if chunk:
                    w.write(chunk)
                print(filename + ' downloaded successfully!!!')
    except urllib.request.URLError as e:
        print("Error :%s" % e)
def Cookdone(url, filename):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        for data in tqdm(response.iter_content()):
            f.write(data)
def Cookdown(url, filename):
    #headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'}
    #cookies = {'_ga': 'GA1.2.282065737.1604285823', 'MUID': '07B92E6562A266AE0A83211366A260EF','aam_uuid': '33272659623977483402062764826775668547','AAMC_mscom_0': 'REGION%7C3','_cs_c': '0','_cs_id': 'cd07a4b3-19b2-a8c7-95e4-7b8fd7c286f9.1605703107.1.1605703107.1605703107.1594299326.1639867107380.Lax.0','_uetvid': 'c457b5101e8a11eb956e2f93309fcf0c','IR_PI': 'f62c6991-299a-11eb-980c-0abbe301118c%7C1605789507507','mbox': 'PC#f8f94dce007c4a3c88788082771689c3.38_0#1668947906|session#af45a09527ce4486be93aff7c2a9adf1#1605704965'}
    import shutil
    req = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    print(req.headers)
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        req.raw.decode_content = False
        shutil.copyfileobj(req.raw, f)
def download(url, path):
    opener = FancyURLopener({}) 
    opener.version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'
    opener.retrieve(url, path)
def down(url, filename):
    proxy = ProxyHandler({})
    opener = build_opener(proxy)
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1 Safari/603.1.30')]
    install_opener(opener)
    urlretrieve(url, filename)
def DownLoad(url, filename):
    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
            f.write(chunk)
def DoneLoad():
    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
        for chunk in progress.bar(r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), expected_size=(total_length/1024) + 1): 
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()
def Download(url, path):
    hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36' }
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(req, path)
def downLoader(url, output_path):
    with DownloadProgressBar(unit='B', unit_scale=True,
                             miniters=1, desc=url.split('/')[-1]) as t:
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36')]
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename=output_path, reporthook=t.update_to)
def downLoad(url, output_path):
    hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36' }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=hdr, verify=False, stream=True)
    with open(output_path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
                f.write(chunk)
```

Here's piece of code to execute every each module :

```
CookDown('http://tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/f7ded4c4-f468-4bdc-96f0-03fd60c5ae81?p1=1604760658&p2=402&p3=2&p4=hcdsxul%2f8qkk8gjjjyomq0ki%2bxwjxulxxeninyf1jqrp3%2bsnzk%2fpwk4dgsnbkfzkzoor4%2bvaixilmxk6r%2bz6%2ba%3d%3d','Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement_10.0.19011.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.appx')
```

Using each module, resulted on the same corrupted file. Any answers will hugely appreciated because im stuck and doesnt have any ideas anymore. Please stackoverflow gods...Come here :D

Comment: "The downloaded files just have 1kb size" -- when this happens to me, what I receive is usually an error page which may be in HTML but can be in some other format. Have you opened said files in a text editor?

Comment: I havent but when the file executed, it wont install and showing "This package either corrupted or invalid" from Appx Installer.

Comment: Try opening the file in a text editor. Hopefully, you'll see a helpful error message.

Comment: Its says "<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE> & You don't have permission to access "http". I have struct by this before but using any modules above, just wont work. Even using Headers or cookies. Is there something wrong with my headers or cookies?

Comment: You need to update your question above with what we've found out, that the site replies with `<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>` instead of with the contents of the file(s) you want.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to download files ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, i had to use Download Manager for that. @Cozdemir